# Question about security. Who else can call a function from my contract?

Tags: contract-deployment, user-safety

A couple of weeks ago I became a victim of crypto scam so I want to ask here first before deployment contract in the mainnet.
If I deploy my contract with hardhat this way:

```
let swapExamples
  const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();

    console.log(
    "Deploying contracts with the account:",
    deployer.address
    );
  
  const SwapExamples = await ethers.getContractFactory("Name")
  
    swapExamples = await SwapExamples.deploy()
    await swapExamples.deployed()

    console.log("Deployed at",swapExamples.address)
```

And I have a transfer from this contract:

```
address beneficiary = MyAddress;

uint256 profit = IERC20(importToken1).balanceOf(address(this));

        if (profit > 0){

        IERC20(importToken1).safeTransfer(beneficiary, profit);
        }
```

Is it possible that some bot will use this transfer function or only a deployer can do it?
And who is able to connect to this contract after deployment? Only me or someone else can do it?
I'm asking this because we usually connect to contracts of Uniswap etc. So anyone can use any contract in blockchain?
Thanks for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want this function to be callable only by the deployer, you can use OpenZeppelin's [ownable](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol) contract, and then add the *onlyOwner* modifier to that function. An example:

```
// contracts/MyContract.sol
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract MyContract is Ownable {
    function normalThing() public {
        // anyone can call this normalThing()
    }

    function specialThing() public onlyOwner {
        // only the owner can call specialThing()!
    }
}
```

More information on this [documentation](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/access-control).